# extract the commented lines only if the following line is not commented

Tags: python, seek

I have a file as follows:

`cat file.txt`

```
# unimportant comment
# unimportant comment
# unimportant comment
# important line
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
# insignificant comment
# significant comment
xyz
xyz
```

I would like to print the lines that start with `'#'` only if the following line is not commented.

I am hoping to extract the following two lines:

```
# important line
# significant comment
```

I tried the following and it does not work:

```py
with open("file.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line[0] == '#':
            pos = fp.tell()
            previous_line_comment = True
        elif line[0] != '#' and previous_line_comment:
            fp.seek(pos)
            print(fp.readline())
            previous_line_commented = False
        else:
            fp.readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's store the value of each comment as we iterate, then output the previous line when we encounter a line which is not a comment.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    ## Set previous comment to None, we will store the comment in here
    previous_comment = None
    for line in file.readlines():
        ## We use startswith to return a boolean T/F if the string starts with '#'
        line_is_comment = line.startswith('#')
        
        if line_is_comment:
            ## If the current line is a comment, set the previous comment to the current line
            previous_comment = line
            continue
        elif previous_comment and not line_is_comment:
            ## If previous comment exists, and the current line is not a comment -> output
            print(previous_comment)
            previous_comment = None
        else:
            previous_comment = None
```

---

Output

```
# important line

# significant comment
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is bitwise AND operator. I believe what you intended to use is logical AND.

```
elif line[0] != '#' and previous_line_comment:
```

Comment: just fixed edited that out. But it won't fix the code